# Catalan numbers with both prefix and suffix

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, combinations, catalan-numbers

In one of the applications of [Catalan number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#Applications_in_combinatorics),it calculates the number of Dyck word in which a string consisting of n $X's$ and n $Y's$ such that no prefix of the string has more $Y's$ than $X's$, and the number given is $C(2n,n) - C(2n,n-1)$. This formula is also correct for any numbers of X and Y, i.e.,$C(m + n,n) - C(m + n,n-1)$

What if the requirement changes to 'no prefix and suffix of the string has more Y's than X's'? It should be more than $C(m + n,n)-2C(m + n,n-1)$, but I am not sure how to determine the exact close form solution. Any ideas?

Comment: Since we have n x's and n y's, using up more x's than y's up to any point, there are inevitably more y's than x's left to use, no? Or do I interpret your question all wrong?

Comment: Thank you Wouter. You are right. For n Xs and N Ys, it only guarantees one side. I changed my OP a little bit, just trying to generalize the solution (both sides), for example, with 2n Xs and n Ys. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These objects are called "bidirectional ballot sequences" and were first introduced in the paper "Constructing MSTD sets using bidirectional ballot sequences" by Yufei Zhao (see http://arxiv.org/pdf/0908.4442.pdf).

Unfortunately, as far as I'm aware, there is no known closed form for the number $B_{n}$ of bidirectional ballot sequences of length $n$ (unlike the case for the Catalan numbers). The paper shows that, asymptotically, $B_{n} = \Theta(2^{n}/n)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the literature. This is really helpful. Yet I'm still wondering whether there is a recursive solution.

Comment: Let me know if you find one! I think it would be quite an impressive result. I know the author of the paper tried for quite a while to find a recursive solution/closed form.